# Mouse-over event on JSTree

Tags: json, jstree

I am using a jstree to display information in an MVC Razor page. The code for jstree looks like this:

```
 $('#app_container').jstree({
                'core': {
                    'data': {
                        "url": "/controller/methodname",
                        "data": function (node) {
                                return { "id": node.id, "parent":node.parent };
                        }
                    }

                },
                "plugins": ["sort"]
       });
```

I want to add a mouse-over event on each node so it displays additional information. I've had a look at [documentation](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=.jstree%20Event&f=hover_node.jstree) but I'm not sure where do I have to add the event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it as an event listener, completely independent of the jstree initialization code:

```
$('#app_container').on("hover_node.jstree", function (node) {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: In case anyone else comes here to look at this, note that the signature of the event function is function (event, data).